# H7 Heart Rate Sensor in C# for Windows Desktop

Tags: c#, window

Specifically, I need to develop a Desktop app that pulls data from H7 Heart Rate Sensor in C# code.
I have searched everywhere and i cant find nothing to help me.
The closest i cam is with this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jn05CU3mxzo&list=UUizfLH6Q2igGUyTWO1bH3YA) tutorial but still it didn't find my H7 Heart Rate Sensor.

```
namespace _123
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> items;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        items = new List<string>();

    }

    private void bGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//button
    {
        if (serverStarted)
        {
            updateUI("server aleredy started");
            return;
        }
        if (rbClient.Checked) {
            startScan();
        }
        else{
        connectAsServer();
        }
    }

    private void startScan() {
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        items.Clear();
        Thread bluetoothScanThread =  new Thread(new ThreadStart(scan));
        bluetoothScanThread.Start();
    }

    BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices;
    private void scan ()
    {

        updateUI("Starting scan...");
        BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
       devices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
        updateUI("Scan complet");
        updateUI(devices.Length.ToString() + "devices discovered");
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in devices)
        {
            items.Add(d.DeviceName);
        }
        updateDeviceList();
    }

    private void connectAsServer()
    {


        Thread bluetoothServerTherad = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServerConnectThread));
        bluetoothServerTherad.Start();
    }

    private void connectAsClient()
    {



    }

    Guid mUUID = new Guid("ECC037FD-72AE-AFC5-9213-CA785B3B5C63");
    bool serverStarted = false;
    private void ServerConnectThread()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        serverStarted = true;
        updateUI("Server started, waiting for clients");
        BluetoothListener blueListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
        blueListener.Start();
        BluetoothClient conn = blueListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
        updateUI("Client has connected");

        Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] received = new byte[1024];
                mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
                updateUI("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));
                byte[] sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world");
                mStream.Write(sent, 0, sent.Length);
            }
            catch (IOException exeption)
            {
                updateUI("Client has disconected!");
            }

            }

    }

    private void updateUI(string message) 
    {
        Func<int> del = delegate()
       {
           tbOutput.AppendText(message + System.Environment.NewLine);
           return 0;

       };
        Invoke(del);

    }

    private void updateDeviceList()
    {
        Func<int> del = delegate()
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = items;
            return 0;

        };
        Invoke(del);
    }

    BluetoothDeviceInfo deviceInfo;
    private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        deviceInfo = devices.ElementAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        updateUI(deviceInfo.DeviceName + " was selected, attemting connect");

        if (pairDevice())
        {
            updateUI("device paired..");
            updateUI("starting conected thread");
            Thread bluetoothClientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientConnectThread));
            bluetoothClientThread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            updateUI("pair failed");
        }

    }

    private void ClientConnectThread()
    {
        BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
        updateUI("attepting connnection");
        client.BeginConnect(deviceInfo.DeviceAddress, mUUID, this.BluetoothClientConnectCallback, client);

    }

    void BluetoothClientConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        BluetoothClient client = (BluetoothClient)result.AsyncState;
        client.EndConnect(result);

        Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;

        while (true)
        {
            while (!ready) ;
            stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        }

    }

    string myPin = "1234";
    private bool pairDevice()
    {
        if (!deviceInfo.Authenticated)
        {
            if (!BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(deviceInfo.DeviceAddress, myPin))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool ready = false;
    byte[] message;
    private void tbText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tbText.Text);
            ready = true;
            tbText.Clear();
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your sensor is probably Bluetooth Low Energy, which is a completely different API from the normal Bluetooth API. So to start with, you'll only get this to work if your computer/tablet/phone has BLE hardware (generally, if it's Bluetooth v4.0, it most likely does) and you have Windows 8. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.aspx for details, including a link to a sample using a heart rate monitor as the example hardware.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am trying to get heart rate (bpm) from a device on a windows using C# but don;t know where yo start in both hardware and software point of view, any suggest?

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding: my previous comment seems to me to have the details you're asking about. You need hardware that supports Bluetooth Low Energy; use your favorite web search engine to learn more about that. The Windows API has support for BLE devices; see the link I provided in my comment for more information about that. If you have a _specific_ question about implementation, you can post a question on SO about that. Don't forget to include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and follow the advice at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2):

This question is old now but here is my answer. So if you have Polar H7 and you are trying to get the Heart rate then I would recommend follow this [Bluetooth Low Energy sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs) and just run the code it should work fine.

After you run this sample click on start enumerating and it will give you list of all the Bluetooth device .

Then find Polar H7 and click on it.

Go to step 2 and hit Connect and choose characteristic and service and you are done.